# VSP1342 - Another instance of the Logger Engine is currently running error when running profiler in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, profiling, profiler

This happens after I have run the profiler once.  the profiler configuration is to watch a dll that is being executed by a separate executable.

The profiling works the first time but I then need to reboot my PC in order to run another profiling session.

What do I need to do to shut down the VS 2008 Logger Engine?  What is the VS 2008 Logger Engine?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to [shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255410%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the logger. Open the *Visual Studio Command Prompt (2008)* from the start menu and then try:

```
vsperfcmd /shutdown
vsperfcmd /off
```

Comment: Alas, that doesn't do it. I've tried GLOBALOFF and DETACH as well.  All report that "the profile monitor does not appear to be running".  When I then try to run the profiler I get VSP1342: Another instance of the Logger Engine is currently running, PRF0010: Launch Aborted, unable to start vsperfmon.exe

Comment: The "shutdown" part works for me, the "off" part may be no longer necessary, it seems.  (VS 2015).